# How can we change the favicon of SE site in Beta?

Tags: support, design, beta-sites, favicon

I am currently associated with a SE site hinduism.stackexchange.com. This SE site is currently in Beta and I found that the favicon for the site is showing 'Hi', i.e., the first two letters from the word 'Hinduism'. This favicon doesn't match with the type of SE site. I had proposed a Hinduism religious symbol from within site's meta and although people too agreed but the moderator was not sure how to change that or whether they can change at all in case site is in beta. So, can anyone please let me know whether moderator can change favicon and what is the procedure for changing that. Also if there are any prerequisites, eg height/width of the image, type (jpg, ico, png, bmp, etc) then please let us know that as well.

Comment: No, ordinary moderators can't change the icon, only Stack Exchange developers. You should discuss this in the per site meta, and let the Community Manager responsible for the site decide, if he/she agree then it can be taken to the next level.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do this is to create a meta post (on Hinduism Meta, not the main meta) with the tag [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Stack Exchange employees monitor that tag across all meta sites in the network. You should get an answer from them in due course, though it may take [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) before you get an answer, and then another arbitrary amount of time before anything is actually done.

Comment: I already created a question (http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/374/can-we-have-a-logo-favicon-for-hinduism-stack-exchange-site) with feature request tag on 9th Apr 2014 but there is no answer to it from Stack Exchange employees. There are only comments from Site moderator and other site members, so thats why I was taking it to the next level, ie, the main meta.

Comment: @Aby fair enough, moderators also have a private chat room where they can directly ping and ask an SE employee about this

Comment: @Aby. Your question on Meta Hinduism has two votes (one of them from me) and no answers. As such, it doesn't look like the community on that site feel that this is an important or urgent thing to do. If you get more traction going there, it'll probably rise up the priority list of the SE community managers, who will then probably respond (and either get it done or explain why they won't).