# What are the requirements for a (beta) site logo?

Tags: support, design, beta-sites, logo

Someone on Sustainable Living SE [proposed](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/300/99) to hold a 'new logo' contest so we can make the beta site a bit more distinct and recognizable. From this [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/164138) I understood that Stack Exchange sites can propose a new logo, although that post doesn't say if this only applies to mature sites or also beta sites. In any case I'd like to know what exactly the requirements are for a site logo? Are there specific dimensions for example? Minimum of padding?

From a look at [the list of all SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) I noticed that all logo's there are 48x48 pixels (favicon.ico is 32x32). Also most logos have several pixels padding, although the exact amount seems to vary. 
Furthermore I see that the dimensions of a logo on a site itself varies; the logo on Biology SE is 139 x 50 pixels, Network Engineering has 218 x 51 and World Building has 238 x 37 pixels for example. Is it correct to say that logo dimensions should be roughly 240 x 51 as a maximum?

Comment: I think it’s basically required that all beta icons are blue speech bubbles. But some betas have successfully changed their logos. See for example here: https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2273

Comment: The answer to this is a bit complicated. For **right now**, beta sites do not get any logo customization at all. Their favicon is the default blue with white initials or occasionally a symbol from a character set (see [anime.se])... this may change in the near future but we’re not sure how, so at this point I’d like to leave this unanswered.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259897/how-can-we-change-the-favicon-of-se-site-in-beta#comment850643_259901

Comment: @Catija I was under the impression Stack Exchange is moving towards "standardization" i.e. making all sites look the same and have same design, in order to make it easier to make changes. Will new sites still get their own logo at all?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I feel like you've missed parts of the discussion. :) One of the big benefits of simplifying the code base is that beta sites will finally get some love - customizations. We're figuring that out... but the unified themes is a way to make new site themes easier to create, not an end of custom themes.

Comment: @Catija thanks, there was  too much to read indeed. Hopefully this will go in a way each site's core members would love. (i.e. discuss custom themes with them before making the big changes.)

Comment: @Catija year later, any update to your comment? :)